# Trisecting angles which can be trisected

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm aware that, in general, arbitrary angles cannot be trisected by a compass and straightedge, but also that it is possible for some specific angles. I've been googling for a while to find:

1. Which angles are trisectable, and
2. What is the procedure for trisecting these angles

It is fairly easy to trisect a $90^\circ$ angle but how does one trisect a $27^\circ$ angle (which one link says is trisectable)? Is there a general method for trisecting angles that are trisectable?

Comment: Three times $27^\circ$ is $81^\circ$.

Comment: I agree. Could you elaborate how this gets me closer to an answer?

Comment: It is $9^\circ$ you are trying to get, isn't it?

Comment: I'm trying to find out how trisectable angles can be trisected in general.

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AngleTrisection.html

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: Thanks, but that link doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: To get $9°$ you need to start from isosceles triangle with angles $72°,72°,36°$ easy to construct via golden ratio and bisect twice the $36°$ angle. I do not know any general construction to trisect trisectable angles. Just like special $3$rd degree equation can be solved easily, but there is no general formula. Each of them must be solved in its own way. Think about construct and trisect a $3°$ angle ....

Comment: @Raffaele: I can see how I could get a $9^\circ$ angle from bisecting a $36^\circ$ angle twice, but how would that help me trisect a $27^\circ$ angle? What are the construction moves with a compass and straightedge that would let me arrive at a $9^\circ$ angle inside a $27^\circ$ angle?

Comment: @Jens I have no idea

Comment: @Jens $$\sin 27°=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}{4}$$ and $$\sin 9°=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{4}$$ Maybe this inspires you...

Comment: @Raffaele: Thanks. I will think about this. But it is astounding to me that I cannot find a procedure for trisecting trisectable angles on this site or indeed any site I have reached using Google. Even just an example (other than $90^\circ$).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If there was a general procedure, that would basically mean that trisection is possible for every angle? General trisection is impossible, and an angle that can be trisected can only be trisected because the "trisected angle" can be constructed independently from the angle you want to trisect? (or the original angle exhibits some special properties you have to take advantage of). Edit: read more carefully, and I think that's the point made by @ Dr.SonnhardGraubner and @ Raffaele

Comment: @N.Bach: Given an angle which is trisectable using a compass and straightedge, I wish to know how to do so. What are the moves I need to do? I would like to know a procedure which is applicable in general, but even a procedure for doing it for a $27^\circ$ angle would be helpful.

Comment: Here's the construction for 27°: construct two other equal angles adjacent to it, in order to obtain an angle of 81°. Construct now a right angle enclosing this angle: the difference is an angle of 9°=27°/3. If you want this INSIDE your original angle, just transport it there with the obvious construction.

Comment: @Aretino: Thanks. I'm not sure what the "obvious construction" is, but I can probably figure it out.

Comment: I think the "obvious construction" mentioned by @Aretino is Euclid I, 23: "On a given straight line and at a point on it to construct a rectilineal angle equal to a given rectilineal angle."

Answer (score 2):

There is no general method of trisecting an angle using compass and straightedge. The nine-degree angle can be constructed using compass and straightedge by first constructing a regular pentagon, for which the interior angle is 72°. Bisect this angle three times and you have a nine-degree angle.

Alternatively, construct a 81° by tripling your angle, construct a pentagon and subtract the 72° angle. You can always multiply your angle by an integer or bisect it.

To confuse matters a bit, a 3° is also constructable: create an hexagon and pentagon inside the same circle and the difference between the interior angles is 12°. Bisect this a couple of times and you get a 3°, which is the interior angle of a 120-gon. You can't do better than this for integral numbers of degrees.

Comment: If you construct 81°, then it is simpler to construct 90° rather than 72°, and 90°-81°=... .